# How do I make special characters display correctly in a webview on all versions of Android?

Tags: android, webview

I have several WebViews inside a ViewPager. I cleaned some html with HtmlCleaner and then extracted some of the html with the following code: `lessons[index-1] = cleaner.getInnerHtml(tagHTML);`. Then I load the html into the WebViews with this code: `webView.loadData(lessons[position], "text/html", null)`.

The text displays properly in the emulator running Android 2.3.3, but on my phone running Android 4.1.1 it shows characters that look like this: `â€œ`.

I noticed that html characters such as `&ldquo;` are converted to symbols such as “ by HtmlCleaner. I tried setting the charset on the WebView to utf-8, but it didn't help.

I don't know if this is related or not, but I noticed that I receive this logcat output when swiping the ViewPager on my phone but not on the emulator: `Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found`

I tried some other inputs and it seems to me that the WebView doesn't display curly quotes and other characters correctly on devices running Jelly Bean. Is there something I can do to make this work?